# How to resolve Mac OS "Alias" in Qt?

Tags: macos, qt, alias

In Qt the API QDir::canonicalPath() can resolve the path for a symbolic link of a directory on Mac OS (symbolic link created through ln -s). But if I try to resolve the path of an "Alias" it doesn't work (created through the context menu "Make Alias"). Is there any way to make it work in Qt? Or I need to right Cocoa wrapper to get the information.

Regards,
Soumya

Comment: Probably related: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-6052 "QFileSystemModel does not show alias files on Mac OS X"